# my auth attempt method is not functioning

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, model

```
 Route::get('/login/admin','Auth\LoginController@showAdminLoginForm');
 Route::post('/login/admin', 'Auth\LoginController@adminLogin');
```

`LoginController`:

```
public function adminLogin(Request $request)
{
    Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'username'   => 'required|username',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);

    if (Auth::guard('user')->attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {

        return redirect()->intended('/dash');
    }

    return back()->withInput($request->only('username', 'remember'));
}
```

Comment: What is the unexpected behavior? Do you get error or it just doesn't log you in or what?

Comment: when i try to login it gets back to login page

Comment: Do you really need separate login logic / form for admin? Why not use same as everyone and have a decent strength password? If you think that having `login/admin` route makes anything more secure - it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

```
public function adminLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'username'   => 'required|username',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);
    $remember_me = $request->has('remember') ? true : false;
    if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password], $remember_me))     
    {
        return redirect()->intended('/dash');
    }

    return back()->withInput($request->only('username', 'remember'));
}
```

Comment: Actually I think the attempt method is not working.

Comment: Can i see your /dash view and do you have additional middleware controls?

Comment: Why do people write like this: `$remember_me = $request->has('remember') ? true : false;`? `$request->has('remember')` returns `true|false`. So you basically have `true ? true : false;` in your code

Comment: I don't try it. Probably work. Thanks for information @NoOorZ24

Comment: I used this route Route::get('/dash','DashController@index')->name('dash');

Comment: The only problem is that attempt method is not functioning

Comment: Remove guard('user') and try that if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password], $remember_me))     
    {
        return redirect()->intended('/dash');
    }

Comment: I edited. Try the last version. I use return redirect()->route('admindashboard'); instead of return redirect()->intended('/dash'); and work.